# Visual Studio 2013 Installation Error For SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am installing visual studio 2013 for my SharePoint 2013 and I came across this below issue.Can any one help me how can I solve this.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Installation Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is permission issue.

Please make sure the ID should be in administrator group and also run the Setup as " Run as Administrator".

check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/it-IT/f9f6307b-f5b4-4ab0-851e-941d38e06a0f/setup-engine-this-security-id-may-not-be-assigned-as-the-owner-of-this-object?forum=vssetup) and also check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838297.aspx